# Banner div and list elements with Ionic Framework

Tags: html, css, listview, ionic-framework

I have a *home screen* with **Ionic Framework**. In the *home screen*, I have a banner and after the banner I have a list view that works like a menu list elements.

My banner actually is a div with this css properties:

```
#banner
{
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    position: fixed;
}

.has-banner
{
    top: 244px;
}
```

And the home screen code:

```
<ion-view title="Home">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-light">
    <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <div>
    <div class="has-header" id="banner">Banner</div>
  </div>
  <ion-content class="has-banner">
    <div class="list">
      <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#/playlists/1">
    <i class="icon ion-person-stalker"></i>
    Option 1
    <span class="badge badge-assertive">0</span>
  </a>
      <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#/playlists/1">
    <i class="icon ion-person-stalker"></i>
     Option 2
    <span class="badge badge-assertive">0</span>
  </a>
      <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#/playlists/1">
    <i class="icon ion-person-stalker"></i>
     Option 3
    <span class="badge badge-assertive">0</span>
  </a>
      <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#/playlists/1">
    <i class="icon ion-person-stalker"></i>
     Option 4
    <span class="badge badge-assertive">0</span>
  </a>
      <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#/playlists/1">
    <i class="icon ion-person-stalker"></i>
     Option 5
    <span class="badge badge-assertive">0</span>
  </a>
      <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#/playlists/1">
    <i class="icon ion-person-stalker"></i>
     Option 6
    <span class="badge badge-assertive">0</span>
  </a>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Everything works fine, but I need to change the banner div for an image tag. My problem is that I need that the list menu begins after the image, but I'm using a width with a 100% to prevent a deformation of the image. I don't know what height value will have the image and my problem is that I don't know what value assign to the top value of the class .has-banner.

Can someone explain me how can I solve the problem?

Here is a demo, please resize the explorer like a smartphone:

https://demoappmovil-c9-chemitaxis.c9.io/

Original thread: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-pane-and-listview-with-scroll/7287/2